# Try to realize Woocommerce pdate cart link after Ajax with Timber

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, timber

I'm using the great Timber plugin for Wordpress and I try to realize this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/2044109) with a Twig Template, but I don't get it to work.

My code looks like this in my functions.php:

```
function my_wc_cart_count() {


    $count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
    ?><a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"
         title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart'); ?>"><?php
    if ($count > 0) {
        ?>
        <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo esc_html($count); ?></span>
        <?php
    }
    ?></a><?php


}

add_action('mytheme_header_action', 'my_wc_cart_count');
```

and this in my base.twig:

```
{% do action('mytheme_header_action') %}
```

Has anyone a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things and got it by my own.

This is my solution:

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments )
{
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start(); ?>

    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>

    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}


function my_wc_cart_count() {
    global $woocommerce;

    ?>

    <div class="header_cart">
        <h5><a href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php _e('Shopping Cart', 'home-shopper'); ?></a></h5>
        <div class="cart_contents">
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php


}

add_action('mytheme_header_action', 'my_wc_cart_count');
```

and still this in base.twig:

```
{% do action('mytheme_header_action') %}
```